# android title was effected by other title(ToolBar)

Tags: android

The first screen is `art's detail`. The title will be `alpha` when I scrolling up. I clicked the other 'art' to another detail UI, then pressing back to Previous UI . Previous UI's title is black why it  become transparent.

[image]

`layout`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/bg_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_service"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_service"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="客服"
            android:textColor="#666"
            android:textSize="9dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_art_buy"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_buy_bg"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="立即购买"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_add_will_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_art_buy"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_add_will_list_bg"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_like_yellow"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="加入心愿单"
            android:textColor="#ff9900"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/rl_bottom_menu"
        android:background="@color/content_divider_color"/>


    <com.hoolay.widget.ScaleImageRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_art_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/divider"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_art_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#1a1a1a"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="15dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_title_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ripple_toolbar_menu"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_back_white"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_title_left"
                android:text="作品详情"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_share_white"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tool_bar_title_text_size_normal"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`java code`

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (toolbar == null) {
                    return;
                }
                float alpha = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() / (float) halfScreenHeight;
                if (alpha <= 2) {
                    if (alpha > 1) {
                        alpha = 1;
                    }
                    toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int) (alpha * 255));
                    tvTitle.setAlpha(alpha);
                    tvRight.setAlpha(alpha);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int)(alpha*255)) in the onCreateView of the fragment or in onCreate of the Activity

Comment: @LucaNicoletti when I press back menu, previous activity didnot invoke onCreate. I setAlpha(float) in onResume() to  fix the bugs. But I do not know why ?

Comment: Do you create & load another fragment when swiping to left? or start another activity?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti start another activity

Comment: Ok, so, on the FirstActivty, inside the onResume method (you need to override it) write the code that turns the action bar into black

Comment: @LucaNicoletti  I said that I can fix the bug. I want to know the reason of the bug.

Comment: The reason is that you don't save the Bundle of your activity, so it get lost when you start another activity

Comment: @LucaNicoletti No!No! My previous activity is still in stack . so I no need save bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

`toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha((int) (alpha * 255));`

You will need to use

`toolbar.getBackground().mutate().setAlpha((int) (alpha * 255));`

Drawables are by default sharing states among each other, calling mutate() will make this particular drawable not sharing state.